# SSIS documentation Reference

Tags: vb.net, ssis

Where is the reference documentation for SSIS Script components? For example, Script Components inherit from a class called UserComponent and the overridden function has a local variable of type: input0buffer.  I am struggling to find documentation that explains what these types are.  I am new to SSIS.

I realise that SSIS packages are created in BIDS.

The Script Components I am using are written using VB.NET.  Is SSIS Script Components an extension of VB.NET?

**Update**
I now realise that the UserComponent class is generated at runtime as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.scriptcomponent.  I still don't understand hpw to find the functions that it implements e.g. Input0_ProcessInputRow.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer I provided re Tiered design?

Comment: @callisto, I have added to the question you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you need to develop script components and tasks appears here: [Developer's Guide (Integration Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136025%28v=sql.100%29)

Comment: Thanks +1, the documentation says that the UserComponent class is generated by a wrapper.  Is there a way to see this class? I assume it is packaged in the dtx file?