# Error while running a SSIS task

Tags: ssis

I have a query that executed fine in SSMS but gives error when I run it as a task in ssis package DTS_E _INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREERROR

My query is something like this

```
Select t1.*
From t1 
Inner join t2
On t1.c1 = t2.c1
And t1.date between ? And ? 
Inner join t3
on t3.c2 = t2.c2
Where 
Date between ? And ?
and c4 like ‘%name%’
```

I am using execute sql task, data access mode is sql command and passing 4 parameters.

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "OLE DB
>   Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error
>   code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB
>   Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component. There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on
>   component "OLE DB Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029
>   while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). The identified
>   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
>   specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
>   Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.
>
> The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with
>   error code 0xC0047020.
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on OLE
>   DB Source returned error code 0xC02020C4. The component returned a
>   failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The
>   meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error
>   is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

These are my detailed error messages

Even I thought it’s something to do with truncation but my columns are exactly same as I am just syncing data from one table to exactly the same table in another server. I created exactly the same table in server 2 from server 1

Comment: I googled `DTS_E _INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREERROR` and it seems to do with data truncation. Please post the full error. Also take a look at the column lengths of your varchar fields in the source and target. In this example, it actually tells you the column with the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459570/ssis-cannot-convert-because-a-potential-loss-of-data

Comment: Please look at the question I linked to and also note the repeated statement in the error: _There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure._. Now go take another look at your log and find the error message before all of this stuff that actually tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Data Enthusiast, please use your enthusiasm and go through your old questions, make an effort to understand the answers and accept them if they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, I thought I posted my comments but looks like I did not. Apparently there were duplicate rows in my select query, I was able to find this in SSDT after locally running the package, went to view and output, there was a detailed error message saying that there are duplicate rows and cannot insert. Thank you all for your help

Comment: This would have been evident if you found the appropriate lines in the error log.